# Azure Service Fabric Reminder GetReminder

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, reminders

With Azure Service Fabric reminders there is a GetReminder method that you can call to determine if a reminder already exists, but if it doesn't it throws a ReminderNotFoundException.  Does anyone know if there is a better way to determine if a reminder exists without having to handle the exception to drive logic flow?

My only thought would be to save a value in the actor state that tells me whether or not a reminder exists instead of calling GetReminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to test for the reminder without throwing an exception. You can see some discussion and a MSFT reply [in this disqus thread](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/azure_service_fabric_actors_timers_and_reminders_94/oldest/).

As you mentioned, using state is a common solution today:

if (!(await this.StateManager.TryGetStateAsync("IsReminderSet")).Value) { ...}